# How to clean variables in an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

In my Application when on pressing on the back button returning to previous activity, the variables are still set up and containing values, my question is how can I reset all variables in any activity, so to act when first launched?

If this helps, i'm having an app that contains three activities; 
In Activity 1: am putting `Bundle.putExtras()` some string to send to the next activity ... 
In Activity 2: also putting some strings in a bundle and sends it to Activity 3 ...

Comment: which kind of variable.. post some codes

Comment: `onActivityResult` clear the global variables (set to defaults again).

Comment: am having different variables, Strings - ArrayList - Thread - Handler - int ...

Comment: I believe StinePike meant "what kind" as in `static` or `instance` variables. I know that's what I was going to ask

Answer (score 2):

Your non-static variables will be cleared and be reset to their defaults when you go back from your `Activity`.

Your static variable can be reset in the `onDestroy()` method of your `Activity`, although doing that defeats the purpose of making them static in the first place.

EDIT: I see you were talking about the previous `Activity`. In this case, just override the `onResume()` of your previous `Activity` to do the clearing of variables,  although I fail to see why you would need to do that.

Comment: this is not true at all. They will only be reset if you make them reset. And where did static variables come into it

Comment: @Doomsknight, I assumed he was talking about the current Activity's variables when he pressed Back, not the previous one. In this context, having static variables deserve a mention makes sense.

Comment: Ok. However `onResume()` will trigger on screen rotation, or hiding then resuming the app. causing data to be cleared when unintended. As mentioned, `onActivityResult` is the best way imo. Just something to consider.

Comment: `onResume()` will not trigger screen rotation unless the screen is rotated, in which case the `Activity` is destroyed and he'll have to manage the state anyway.

Comment: I think you mis-read my comment, if he rotates the screen, it will trigger `onResume()` which will reset all his variables, in your given solution.

Comment: so here is the case, am having a thread that is started when I press on a button on the first activity, this thread is pinging a specific port to see what IPs are available, now when I choose an IP (device) i can send him files or chat with him, when I return to the main activity (where the pinging is done) and press another time on the button to ping devices, i don't know why it is not blocking on the .accept() ...

Comment: @Doomsknight, `onResume()` is always called after `onActivityResult()`, so it'll get called anyway. No need to use `onActivityResult()` if `onResume()` will get called anyway.

Comment: You are completely missing the point, you dont want it to be called in `onResume()` as it will be called when you dont want it too as well. (on screen rotate etc). It would cause far more issues.

Answer (score 0):

You can `finish()` your current activity after you `call` your `second activity`. This will clean variable in your ex activity.

Comment: i don't think this is the best solution, when the second activity starts the previous activity is being finished by `finish();` , now when pressing on back button it will not return to the previous activity because it had been finished, instead it is closing the app.

Comment: You can override you onBackPressed() method of your second activity and you can recall your first activity.

Answer (score -1):

Just initialize all variables on the onResume() method.
That way, every time your activity comes into play, your data is wiped out.